# Having trouble using php json_encode on local server

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, wamp, json

In my controller I'm getting product data from Affilinet API in the form of xml, and creating an html string for product listing. After that I use php `json_encode` function to encode an array containing that html, something like

```
$data = array('listHtml' => $listHtml,'pagingHtml':$pagingHtml);
echo json_encode($data);
```

On my staging and live servers, the code is working perfectly fine, but with the same data, the code is returning me this on local server

```
{"listHtml":null,"pagingHtml":"some html"}
```

The $listHtml includes some german characters. The problem is that on my online servers, the code treats $listHtml as UTF-8 encoded, but on local server it's treated as something else.

Other than that, if I print out a string including some German characters, it works fine on online servers but the German characters are messed up on local server. So how do I configure my local server to interpret text as UTF-8 encoded

Comment: Why don't you set your local server to UTF-8?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with `json_encode`. You need to find the relevant line of code where on your local system where NULL is not expected for that value. This needs basic debugging, best done with a step-debugger like xdebug. Also activate error reporting to the very highest level and track the logfile.

Comment: $listHtml is a string containing html to be placed by a jQuery method. The html contains some list items, divs, and the product data received from the API. Some of the data contains german characters which cause problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Apache, then you can change the httpd.conf file and add or change (if it's already there) to:

```
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Answer (score 3):

You could always UTF-8 encode your string by using [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) before you actually `json_encode` your HTML.

```
$data = array('listHtml' => utf8_encode($listHtml),'pagingHtml' => utf8_encode($pagingHtml));
echo json_encode($data);
```

The reason this may happen is if your HTML has some other encoding than UTF-8 which does not support the German characters, `json_encode` may fail to parse the given input.

For instance:

```
echo json_encode(array('a' => mb_convert_encoding('Üß', 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8')));
```

return `{"a":null}` due to German characters inside a ISO-8859-1 encoded string.

Comment: Lol, utf8 encoding NULL. What should that make for a différence?

Comment: He said that the output gave NULL, not the input. If it's an encoding issue, encoding it before processing it may solve the issue.

Comment: Yes sure, but not at that place. `json_encode` is pretty straight forward, at that place `$listHtml` seems to be already `NULL`.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I didn't assume $listHTML is NULL when given to `json_encode`. If the encoding is something else than UTF-8, and contains german characters, the input given to the function may be corrupt and therefor making it produce NULL output.

Comment: For instance, `echo json_encode(array('a' => mb_convert_encoding('Üß', 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8')))` produce `{"a":null}`.

Comment: The input, i.e. $listHtml is not NULL but it contains german characters. Well I can always utf-8 encode the string but it is an overhead, since the code is running fine on live and staging servere :(

Comment: I don't see the overhead? You just ensure that the string input is UTF-8. On live and stage the string probably already are UTF-8 and no processing will be done.

My answer seem to solve the problem, or am I wrong?

Comment: mb_get_encoding has a sufficient overhead if the string contains a decorated html listing for 100 products. My purpose of posting this question was to find out why it's having different behavior on my local server and how to fix it..

*So how do I configure my local server to interpret text as UTF-8 encoded*

Comment: I see, I would have suggested the answer below me but I read it didn't seem to make any difference for you. Did you restart your server in between?